# TC program to disply max value outof 20 integers values using Function

Tags: c, function

```
int maxval(int *,int x);
int max,arr[20];
void main()
{
  printf("Enter the Numbers:");
  scanf("%d",&max);
  max=maxval(&arr[0],20);


  getch();
}

int maxval (int *list,int x)
{
  int i,maxnum=*list[0];

  for (i=1;i<=x-1;i++)
  if (maxnum<*list[i])
    maxnum=*list[i];
  return maxnum;
}
```

This Code is Not working.... :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
*list[0]
```

you just need

```
list[0]
```

same for `*list[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

--KRG

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxval(int *,int x);
int max,arr[20];

int main() {
  arr[0] = 1;
  arr[1] = 69;
  arr[2] = 10;

  max = maxval(&arr[0],3);
  printf("%d", max);
  getch();
  return 0;
}

int maxval (int *list,int x) {
  int i, maxnum=list[0];
  for (i=1;i<=x-1;i++)
    if (maxnum < list[i])
      maxnum = list[i];
  return maxnum;
}
```